# How to describe this.props and this.store?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I inherit from the react component of Cell. But the linter swears: The "props" property does not exist in the "Creative" type. The same is true for this.state and this.setState.

```
export default class Creative extends Cell<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { rowData: { creative }, rowNumber } = this.props;
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The Creative class inherits Cell so you have to add  to the Creative class and in its props extend from the other props of the other component.

```
interface CreativeProps extends CellProps { //Its own props}

interface CreativeState { //Its state }

export default class Creative extends React.Component<CreativeProps , CreativeState> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { rowData: { creative }, rowNumber } = this.props;
}
```

However, these are already implicit in Creative as long as you have declared them in Cell. The above (//...) is if you'd like to add props and state extra

You have an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-tujz6

Comment: This will not solve the problem with ths.props, this.state, this.setState. They need to somehow inherit from React.Component

Comment: And if you want that Creative inherit Cell's behaviour you could have this: export default class Creative extends Cell<CreativeProps, CreativeState>